# Navigating to Pycharm Virtual Environment

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I created a new Python project and a virtual environment using Pycharm, however I am unable to navigate to the virtual environment using Ubuntu terminal. Could anyone share how I could enter the virtual environment through the Ubuntu terminal and run python files with the packages available in that specific environment.

My pycharm terminal shows this by default:
`(conditional_slim_gan) arsh@Arsh:~/Desktop/machine learning/Outlier_dataset$`

Comment: try: `source mypython/bin/activate`, where `mypython` is your virtual environment name

Comment: Navigate to pycharm, preferences, project interpreter and get the path to the corresponding virtual environment. In shell then run `source PATH_TO_VENV/bin/activate`

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried the command and it worked.@vestronge

Comment: Thanks for answering, using just the environment name showed error, but adding the complete path worked.@AhmetTavli

Answer (score 0):

To activate the created virtual environment, run the following command in ubuntu terminal:

```sh
source /Desktop/machine learning/Outlier_dataset/bin/activate
```